# How to call (MySQL) Database Stored Procedure using JPA (Entity Manager): When Procedure already stored in database

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, entitymanager

Use Case:

I have the procedure stored in the database:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`DEVDBA`@`%` PROCEDURE `TestReporting`()
begin 

truncate table `report_controller_total_request`;

insert into `report_controller_total_request` 
select count(*) as total_no_of_requests from log_request;

end
```

*** Now I want to call this stored procedure from the code base using EntityManager

```
    public void UpdateServer() {
        
        System.out.println("Update Server Start");
        
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        entityManager = EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("TestReporting");
        
        boolean isExceuted = storedProcedure.execute();
        
        System.out.println("Update Server Done: "+isExceuted);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();
    }
```

I have tried different versions of the code, this is the last I tried before posting.

I'm not able to call the procedure, it gives me some error every time

Update Server Start

Update Server Done: false

Summary:

I already have the procedure stored in the database, I want the java code using EntityManagger to call the procedure, which in turn updates the database table.

Note: I'm using JNDI for the database connection.

Comment: Can you post the error? Does your procedure work when invoked manually from database?

Comment: Any error(s) should be added to the question to help us help you.

Comment: 16:26:54.611 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - FUNCTION CALL does not exist
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
 at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
 at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
 at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.execute(ProcedureCallImpl.java:653)